# OCaml combine fprintf and sprintf

Tags: ocaml

I want to write a function that can either print something to a string or to an `out_channel`. I'm stuck with the internal `format` stuff however.

My approach is something like this:

```ml
type pr_target = Channel of out_channel | StrRef of string ref
let my_print target fmt = match target with
  | Channel ch -> fprintf ch fmt
  | StrRef str -> str := !str ^ sprintf fmt
```

This gives a type errors as the two uses of `fmt` are different: `fprintf` takes an `('a, out_channel, unit) format` while `sprintf` takes an `('a, unit, string) format`.

How can I write such a function? I'm not super proficient with modules or OCamls polymorphism.

Comment: This really feels like an XY problem. What actual problem are you trying to solve? Have you looked at the [`Format`](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Format.html) module?

Comment: I'm working with a large codebase that uses `Printf`'s `fprintf` everywhere, so I cannot simply replace everything with `Format`. I thought a minimally-invasive solution would therefore be to write a variant of `fprintf` that doesn't necessarily take an `out_channel` but can also write to a `string ref`.

Comment: There is something of the sort in the "batteries" library. Not sure if that meets your needs http://ocaml-batteries-team.github.io/batteries-included/hdoc2/BatBuffer.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Format.formatter can be use either buffers or out_channel as formatting backend:

```ml
let b = Buffer.create 10
let bfmt = Format.formatter_of_buffer b
let ch = Out_channel.open_text "filename"
let cfmt = Format.formatter_of_out_channel ch
let either fmt = Format.fprintf (if Random.bool () then bfmt else cfmt) fmt
```

Moreover, in general, you want to use `asprintf` rather than `sprintf` in order to be able to use `%a` and `%t` specifier:

```ml
let s =
  Format.asprintf "@[<v>This is a list [%a]@]"
    Format.(pp_print_list pp_print_string) ["one"; "two"]
```

Comment: Thank you. While using `Format` seems like a nice option, I unfortunately don't have it because I'm working with a codebase that massively uses `Printf`'s `fprintf`. I've already determined that there is no direct way to create an `out_channel` that writes to a `string ref`, so is there any option to do what I want using `Printf`? e.g. by writing a similar function as I had in mind in the question?

Comment: Your `my_print` function is essentially trying to be `Format.fprintf`. So it would be easier to switch to `Format.fprintf` rather than trying to reimplement it. (It is possible to define other printf interpreter, but it is still a new function to use everywhere). Another option would be to only generate strings, and prints that to `out_channel` when needed.

Comment: Thank you, this was after all the best solution. I could replace the `Printf` with `Format` in the codebase after all -- it came down to just changing a few `open` statements!